# Output data to Datastore with Entity by Google Cloud Client Library for Java

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My pipeline store data to Datastore.
When I used google api service to create entity object, there were not any compile error.
As following page, I should Google Cloud Client Library instead of Google api service.
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/datastore/v1beta2

So that I changed my code for using Google Cloud Client Library for Java. But a compile error is occured.

> The method apply(PTransform,OutputT>) in the type PCollection is not applicable for the arguments 
>    (DatastoreV1.Write)

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `DatastoreIO`, and not the Google Cloud Client Library for Datastore, unless you want to deal with the overhead of writing your own `PTransform`. Can you post the code or more details about the implementation?

Based on the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/datastore-io#writing-to-datastore) your code should look like this:

```
PCollection<Entity> entities = ...;
entities.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId(projectId));
```

The documentation for `DatastoreV1.Write` can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/datastore/DatastoreV1.Write). There is not much else I can answer unless you most the implementation details. I'd post this as a comment but unfortunately do not have enough reputation.